# Concatenating columns in for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I have a sample data frame `coords` with pairs of coordinates and an `id:

```
> coords
  coords.x1 coords.x2  id
1 -77.06983  38.89720   A
2 -77.02854  38.89055   B
3 -77.04489  38.88567   C
```

My objective is to loop through each row in the data frame, concatenate the coordinates of each row and then print out the id of each row.  The result should be something like:

```
[1] "-77.06983,  38.89720"
[1] "A" 

[2] "-77.02854,  38.89055"
[2] "B" 

[3] "-77.04489,  38.88567"
[3] "C"
```

But the following code produces something different:

```
for (i in coords) {

  print(coords[i, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2")])

  print(coords[i, "id"])

} 


  coords.x1 coords.x2
1 -77.06983  38.89720
2 -77.02854  38.89055
3 -77.04489  38.88567
[1] "A" "B" "C"
     coords.x1 coords.x2
NA          NA        NA
NA.1        NA        NA
NA.2        NA        NA
[1] NA NA NA
     coords.x1 coords.x2
NA          NA        NA
NA.1        NA        NA
NA.2        NA        NA
[1] NA NA NA
```

Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong syntactically in this for loop?  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(coords)
structure(list(coords.x1 = c(-77.06983, -77.028545, -77.0448866666667
), coords.x2 = c(38.897195, 38.8905533333333, 38.8856716666667
), id = c("A", "B", "C")), .Names = c("coords.x1", "coords.x2", 
"id"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change to

```
for (i in 1:nrow(coords)) {
.
.
.
}
```

and try to avoid for loop if possible cuz they are quite slow in R
try function like map() from purrr or apply familiy function like lapply sapply and stuff.

```
print_coords = function(i,x){
  print( x[i,c("coords.x1", "coords.x2")])
  print(x[i,"id"])
}

invisible(lapply(1:nrow(coords),print_coords,x = coords))
```